Proportion of vertices in components of size $k$ in Erdos Renyi
Consider $G(n,c/n)$ the Erdos-Renyi graph on $n$ vertices with the probability of having an edge between any two vertices is $c/n$. Let $X_{n,k}$ be the proportion of vertices in size-$k$ components. What is $\lim_{n \to \infty}E(X_{n,k}) = M_k$ ? I want to verify my work and see if the final answer is correct.
My work: $E(X_{n,k}) = P(\#C(1)=k)$ where $C(1)$ is the component containing the vertex $1$. Now, $P(\#C(1)=k) = \binom{n-1}{k-1}P(\text{vertices }1,2,\dots,k \text{ are connected})\left(1-\frac{c}{n}\right)^{k(n-k)}$.
Now, $P(\text{vertices }1,2,\dots,k \text{ are connected}) = P(\text{vertices }1,2,\dots,k-1 \text{ are connected}) \left(1-(1-\frac{c}{n})^k\right)$ because $\left(1-(1-\frac{c}{n})^{k-1}\right)$ is the probability that vertex $k$ is attached to at least one of $1,2,\dots,k-1$.
Putting all this together, we get
$$
\frac{M_k}{M_{k-1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n-1}{k-2}} \frac{\left(1-\frac{c}{n}\right)^{k(n-k)}}{\left(1-\frac{c}{n}\right)^{(k-1)(n-k+1)}}\left(1-(1-\frac{c}{n})^{k-1}\right).
$$
In the limit, the product of first term and last term converges $c$ and the second term converges to $e^{-c}$. So $M_k = M_{k-1} ce^{-c} = (ce^{-c})^{k-1}M_1$. Now, $M_1 = lim_{n \to \infty}(1-\frac{c}{n})^{n-1} = e^{-c}$. Hence, $M_k = e^{-kc}c^{k-1}$.

Are you still looking for an answer?

As abacaba's answer states, you've miscalculated the probability that $1,2,\dots,k$ are connected, since it may not be that $1,2,\dots,k-1$ are connected. Here it is better to compute the probability that $1,2,\dots,k$ are connected as a sum over all spanning connected graphs on $1,2,\dots,k$. Since there are $k^{k-2}$ spanning trees on $1,2,\dots,k$ (by Cayley's formula), the probability that the graph on $1,2,\dots,k$ is exactly one of these trees is
$$ k^{k-2} p^{k-1} (1-p)^{\binom{k}{2}-(k-1)} .$$
While it is possible that the graph on $1,2,\dots,k$ is connected but not a tree, this is so much smaller than the above probability (assuming $k \ll \sqrt{n}$), since the number of graphs get at most an additional factor of $O(k^2)$ per additional edge, but also an additional factor of $p=c/n$ per additional edge. Thus the expected proportion of vertices in size $k$ components is approximately
$$ \binom{n-1}{k-1} k^{k-2} p^{k-1} (1-p)^{\binom{k}{2}-(k-1) + k(n-k)} \approx \frac{n^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} k^{k-2} \left( \frac{c}{n} \right)^{k-1} e^{-ck} = \frac{(ck)^{k-1} e^{-ck}}{k!} .$$

I think there is a mistake in computing the probability that vertices $1,2,\cdots, k$ are connected. The problem is that it might be the case that vertices $1,2, \cdots, k$ are connected, but $$1,2,\cdots, k - 1$$ are not. For example, when $k = 3$, it might be the case that vertex $1$ and $2$ are both connected to $3$, but $1$ and $2$ are not connected.
The correct answer can be found in this post.
